# Struggling to update a react state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I have a login form and I'm trying to redirect the user to the dashboard if they successfully login.
I'm storing the jsonwebtoken in the local storage if the user checks the "RememberMe" option, otherwise I'm storing it in session storage instead.

The problem is that when I put the credentials and click the login button, it works but then I immediately get redirected to the login component again ( **as if the jsonwebtoken doesn't exist** )
I tried passing the token as a prop to the login component to see what's happening, and it's **null** despite it **existing inside the local/session storage**
If I **refresh the page** and try again it works correctly because the token is already in the storage, which means that the **state** for my token isn't updating correctly in the App component.

Here's the code for the App component where my routes are defined (using react-router v6.3.0) and for the login form.

**App:**

```
function App() {
    const [token, setToken] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem("JWToken") || sessionStorage.getItem("JWToken")
    );

    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                <Route
                    path="/login"
                    element={<Login token={token as string} />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/dashboard"
                    element={token ? <Dashboard /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/tickets"
                    element={token ? <Tickets /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/administration"
                    element={
                        token ? <Administration /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
                    }
                />
            </Routes>
        </>
    );
}
```

**Login:**

```
function Login({ token }: { token: String }) {
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
    const [showDemoRoles, setShowDemoRoles] = useState(false);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const URL = "http://localhost:5033/auth/login";
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(URL, {
                email: email.toLowerCase(),
                password,
            });

            if (res.status === 200) {
                if (rememberMe) {
                    localStorage.setItem("JWToken", res.data.token);
                } else {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("JWToken", res.data.token);
                }

                navigate("/dashboard");
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            toast.error(error?.response.data.msg);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to misunderstanding of how `useState` works in this case. When App component is mounted - expression in the `useState` is evalueated and result is saved, and it does not re-evalueate itself. It will do only if `App` is `unmounted` and `mounted` back again. So you need to call `setToken` yourself manually. You should pass the `setToken` function instead of `token` as a `prop` to `Login` component and call it just before the `navigate` function -  `setToken(res.data.token)`.

So changes:

1. Pass the setToken function from App to Login components as a prop

```
<Login setToken={setToken} />
```

2. Change props of the Login component

```
interface IProps {
  setToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>;
}


function Login({ setToken }: IProps)
```

3. Call setToken just before navigate

```
if (res.status === 200) {
  if (rememberMe) {
    localStorage.setItem("JWToken", res.data.token);
  } else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("JWToken", res.data.token);
  }
  setToken(res.data.token);
  navigate("/dashboard");
}
```